# How may I convert java custom Object to String and back again

Tags: java, serialization

I would like to write a converter to convert my custom object to DTO and back. How do I approach it?

I have 2 classes Appointment and Doctor which is a subclass of Appointment. I would like to have the converter as simple as possible. 
I am not looking for straight answer, would appreciate tips on how to approach it.

below classes have getters and setters:

```java
public class Doctor {

  private long id;

  private String name;

  private String surname;

  private String key;
}

public class Appointment {


  private long id;

  private String description;

  private Doctor doctor;

  private Date appointmentDate;

}


//converter
public class ConverterComponent {
public AppointmentDTO convert(Appointment appointment){
    AppointmentDTO appointmentDTO = new AppointmentDTO();
    appointmentDTO.id = appointment.getId();
    appointmentDTO.description = appointment.getDescription();
    appointmentDTO.doctor = appointment.getDoctor().toString();
    appointmentDTO.appointmentDate = appointment.getAppointmentDate().toString();
    return appointmentDTO;
}
}
```

I would like to write another convert(AppointmentDTO appointmentDTO) method in ConverterComponent which will return the Appointment object back.

Could it be done just by parsing Object to json and back again?

Thanks,

Comment: "*I am not looking for straight answer, would appreciate tips on how to approach it*" StackOverflow is not for tips. It is not for broad questions advising you how to structure your application. It is for *specific* technical questions with *specific* answers. See [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: "Could it be done just by parsing Object to json and back again?" no, the structures don't match. It's also not possible to always map things bi-directionally, so even though mapping **to** DTO is easy, mapping back from it isn't necessarily. But what's this about convertin an object to a `String`? You're not converting to String, but to a DTO. And your classes seem to lack a proper implementation of `toString()`.